# How do I get the Epic Fantasy?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance

In Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance, I want to make a spirit called the Tyranto Rex. I need 1 Epic Fantasy and 3 Intrepid Fantasy. I have the 3 Intrepid Fantasy, but I don't have the Epic Fantasy. My friend, who has beat the game 3 times, told me that getting the Epic Fantasy is hard. Where can I get the Epic Fantasy? Also, is there a specific number of Epic Fantasies that you can get?

[image: Tyranto Rex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get an Epic Fantasy, but for one of them, you'll likely want to pass.

### Kill Monsters

It can only be obtained through killing as Riku. As Riku, you'll need to find and beat the Special Portals 4, 5, or 6 on either Prankster's Paradise, or Three Mouseketeers worlds, or 4 or 5 on Symphony of Sorcery. Once you beat it, you will get an Epic Fantasy. For the locations of each of these portals, you'll likely want to consult [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997779-kingdom-hearts-3d-dream-drop-distance/faqs/64741).

### Killing Your Pets

Your dream eaters, when they die, will drop dream pieces. In the case of [Ursa Circus](http://www.khwiki.net/Ursa_Circus), it will drop an Epic Fantasy. But, seeing as how you need an Epic Fantasy to make an Ursa Circus, this is not a very viable way to get Epic Fantasies.

### Limit on Quantity?

There is no limit on the quantity, it can just take you a while to get. Every time you beat one of the special portals listed above, you will get one, so you can horde them all and gather as many as you like. You can even build an army of Tyranto Rex's if you'd like. Certainly possible, though it will take a while.

Comment: Can't you get Ursa Circus by AR card? I think I already have Ursa Circus and 2 other dream eaters because of AR cards.

Comment: Also... How do you kill your pets?

Comment: You will get 1 of Meowjesty, Ursa Circus, or Sudo Neku randomly with one of the AR cards. If you got Ursa Circus, then yes, you can kill him. As for how they die, when your dream eaters run out of health, they will start flashing, and you have to go over and mash buttons to save them. If you don't save them, they die and drop items. So you don't actually kill them, instead you simply stand over their bodies as they die. Much less cruel.